# Flutter: Unable to update variable state

Tags: flutter, dart, state, state-management

In my application, there is a section to add payment. To add a payment, admin will:

1. select a user
2. enter amount
3. select **from date**
4. select **to date**

And save it.

**Goal:** I want to update **from date** dynamically, based on previous date.

**Example Case:**

1. we added first payment of a user, from `1st June 2019` to `1st September 2019`
2. when we try to make second payment, when the customer is selected; I want to get last payment **to date** as **from date**, populated automatically. (**to date** from db to **from date** in form)

It can't be done at initialization, because the date varies for each user, so we can do it upon user selection.

**What I've done:**

I've almost done everything, but having issue in updating field value.

**I've done these steps:**

1. created a function which executes, when the user is selected
2. function queries db, and pulls last payment detail
3. and returns **to date** field value of previous payment
4. the **from date** field value is set inside the same function like this:

   ```
    setState(() {
      _fromDate = DateTime.parse(toDate);
    });
   ```

**Problem:**

Printing `_fromDate` inside `setState` function prints correct value, but it's `null` outside.

Please tell me, how can I update value properly and get rid off this issue?

**Update:** The `Widget` code is below: (the `state` is set as mentioned above, after getting data from db)

```
DateTimeField(
    onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _fromDate = val),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
    onChanged: (DateTime newValue) {
      setState(() {
        _fromDate = newValue;
      });
    },
    onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
      return showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          firstDate: DateTime.now(),
          initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
          );
    },
  );
```

Comment: can you add widget's code to see how you init and use _fromDate?

Comment: @KirillMatrosov I've updated question, please check...

Comment: you didnt point `format` for `DateTimeField` and `lastDate` for `showDatePicker`. This code is not valid. Check please, perhaps this is problem

Comment: updated code by adding `format: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),` and `lastDate: DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 30))` but still same issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) class to handle run time text field changes.

> Whenever the user modifies a text field with an associated TextEditingController, the text field updates value and the controller notifies its listeners. Listeners can then read the text and selection properties to learn what the user has typed or how the selection has been updated.

The process is pretty simple, just **follow these steps:**

1. Create `controller`:

   ```
   TextEditingController _fromDateController = new TextEditingController();
   ```
2. Assign it to your `DateTimeField` like this:

   ```
   DateTimeField(
      ...
      controller: _fromDateController,
   );
   ```
3. Update `onSaved` method of your field:

   ```
   DateTimeField(
      ...
      onSaved: (val) => _fromDateController.text = val.toString(),
   );
   ```
4. Update `controller` when you get data from db:

   ```
   setState(() {
      _fromDateController.text = toDate;
   });
   ```
5. Lastly, don't forget to `dispose` it:

> Remember to dispose of the TextEditingController when it is no longer needed. This will ensure we discard any resources used by the object.

```
    @override
    void dispose() {
       _fromDateController.dispose();
       ...

       super.dispose();
   }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll give it try and get back to you!

Comment: thank you so much, it worked but it displays Date + Time, I only need to display Date `(Year / Month / Day)`. How can I do that?

Comment: try this code for date formatting: `DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').format(DateTime.parse(DATE_STRING))`